# Unable to migrate api operations from deprecated developer portal to new developer portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Currently facing two issues while migrating from old developer portal to new developer portal

1)List of APIS, I can see in while customizing but its not visible, when I try to open the link in new incognito window(snapshot attached)

[image: No API List is populating in new developer portal when opened in incognito window]

2)All the api operations related to different modules in developer portal, I am unable to migrate (snapshot attached)

[image: APIs List in deprecated developer portal]

- To resolve first issue -I tried to publish the portal and asked for admin access for the developer portal
- To resolve second issue - I tried below steps as mentioned on the Microsoft site

If your API Management is in a virtual network and is exposed to the Internet via Application Gateway, refer to this documentation article for precise configuration steps. You need to:
Enable connectivity to the API Management's management endpoint.
Enable connectivity to the new portal endpoint.
Disable selected Web Application Firewall rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to migrate Api operations from deprecated developer portal to new developer portal.

- It seems like you’re experiencing difficulties while migrating from the deprecated developer portal to the new one.
  **Try to follow steps :**
  [image]
- **List of APIs not visible:**  If you can see the list of APIs while customizing but not when opening the link in a new incognito window, it could be due to caching issues. Browsers often cache web pages, so it’s possible that the incognito window is loading a cached version without the updated list.
- Try clearing your browser cache and refreshing the page in the incognito window to see if that resolves the problem.
  Follow the below Steps to Add a  **New API**:

[image]

- **Unable to migrate API operations:**  Migrating API operations from the old developer portal to the new one may require some additional steps.
- The instructions you mentioned about enabling connectivity to the API Management’s management endpoint, enabling connectivity to the new portal endpoint, and disabling selected Web Application Firewall rules are specific to scenarios where API Management is in a virtual network and exposed to the Internet via Application Gateway.
- If your setup matches this scenario, you should follow the steps outlined in the Microsoft documentation you mentioned.
  [image]

Refer to this  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-deprecated-migration)  to migration of operations

- However, if your API Management setup doesn’t involve a virtual network and Application Gateway, these steps may not be applicable to your situation. In that case, you should review the documentation provided by Microsoft for the specific migration process you need to follow. It’s possible that there are alternative steps or requirements for your particular migration scenario.
- If you’re still having trouble after following the appropriate migration documentation, I would recommend reaching out to Microsoft’s support team or the community forums for further assistance. They will have the most up-to-date information and can provide you with specific guidance based on your setup and requirements.
  To find the most up-to-date and accurate information, I recommend visiting the official Microsoft documentation website for Azure API Management.
- Go to the Azure API Management documentation homepage:refer to this  [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/)
  In the search bar at the top of the page, enter relevant keywords related to your migration scenario, such as “migrate to new developer portal” or “deprecated portal migration.”

Comment: Thanks for your reply to my query. I can see the list of APIS while customizing, but not when opening the link in a new incognito window. I even cleared the cache still the same issue , Do I lack any appropriate permission/privileges still ?

Comment: Can you let me know how to reach out to Microsoft's support team(by asking query under their Q&A section). Any specific community forums id/ account plz?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/

Comment: Are you aware that AI-generated text is banned on Stack Overflow? How much of this answer did you write yourself, and how much did you copy in from ChatGPT?

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: @tchrist, I have reproduced the above answer, but I took the text from AI going forward I will take care while posting the answer.